# Divide date_diff in days with 365 to get number of years

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery, datediff

I made a `DATE_DIFF` between first purchase and second purchase when I realized that I get wrong number of orders in year 0. A customer that has made a first order in Oct 2020 and second order January 2021 ends up in the bin for customers that has done their second order 1 year later - the year has changed for the new order but it's only a few months between the orders.

I tried to do a `DATE_DIFF` with days in difference instead of years, and divide it with 365, but this gave me decimal numbers as years. Below is my query that I use in DataStudio, I'm grouping numbers of orders by calc_yearsBetweenFirstTwoOrders there. Does anyone know how to handle this?

```
DATE_DIFF(a.casted_order_datetime, a.first_customer_purchase_date, YEAR) AS yearsBetweenFirstTwoOrders,
DATE_DIFF(a.casted_order_datetime, a.first_customer_purchase_date, DAY) / 365 AS calc_yearsBetweenFirstTwoOrders,
DATE_DIFF(a.casted_order_datetime, a.first_customer_purchase_date, DAY) AS daysBetweenFirstTwoOrders,
DATE_DIFF(a.casted_order_datetime, a.first_customer_purchase_date, WEEK) AS weeksBetweenFirstTwoOrders,
DATE_DIFF(a.casted_order_datetime, a.first_customer_purchase_date, MONTH) AS monthsBetweenFirstTwoOrders,

CASE WHEN (DATE_DIFF(a.casted_order_datetime, a.first_customer_purchase_date, DAY) = 0) THEN 'newCustomer' 
     WHEN (DATE_DIFF(a.casted_order_datetime, a.first_customer_purchase_date, DAY) > 0) THEN 'returningCustomer' 
ELSE NULL END AS customerSegment,

CASE WHEN (article_price BETWEEN 0 AND 1000) THEN 'price 0-1000'
     WHEN (article_price BETWEEN 1000 and 2000) THEN 'price 1000-2000'
     WHEN (article_price BETWEEN 2000 and 3000) THEN 'price 2000-3000'
     WHEN (article_price BETWEEN 3000 and 4000) THEN 'price 3000-4000'
     WHEN (article_price BETWEEN 4000 and 5000) THEN 'price 4000-5000'
     WHEN (article_price BETWEEN 5000 and 6000) THEN 'price 5000-6000'
ELSE 'price > 6000' END AS article_price_binned,


from (



SELECT 
DISTINCT order_id,
first_customer_purchase_date,
CAST(TIMESTAMP(order_datetime)as DATE) as casted_order_datetime,
order_datetime as order_datetime,
customer_id,
orderrow_id,
article_title,
main_image,
article_price,
category_level_1,
category_level_2,
category_level_3,
merchant,
traffic_source,
is_return,
Order_Product_Age_Days,
order_shipping_time_max,
Quantity,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_datetime desc ) AS RN
  
FROM `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.sandbox.xxxxxx`

)A

WHERE order_datetime BETWEEN PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) 
AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the whole number from the output when you divided the date difference with 365 to represent the year difference. To do this you can adjust your query to this:

```
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(CAST(DATE_DIFF(a.casted_order_datetime, a.first_customer_purchase_date, DAY)/365 AS STRING),r'^(\d+)\.\d+') AS INT64) AS calc_yearsBetweenFirstTwoOrders
```

NOTE: I casted it back to INT64 just so it won't be treated as string.

I tested it with this example:

```
SELECT
  CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(CAST(DATE_DIFF(DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2020-10-01', DAY)/365 AS STRING),r'^(\d+)\.\d+') AS INT64) AS calc_yearsBetweenFirstTwoOrders
```

2021-01-01 and 2020-10-01:

[image]

2021-01-01 and 2020-01-01:

[image]

2021-01-01 and 2019-06-01:

[image]

Comment: Huge thanks! I don't get the regex though - could you explain what it does in this case?

Comment: @SevgiCamuz For the solution I used REGEXP_EXTRACT where I used the expression `^(\d+)\.\d+` to match the decimal output of DATE_DIFF. \d represents a singe digit, \d+ represents multiple digits and ^ to represent start of the line. With these it will match any string that starts with digits separated by a dot and followed by digits. If you notice \d+ is enclosed in (), which extracts the value of \d+ and in this case the whole number.

Comment: For more information you can check [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) and [regex syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax#black-lives-matter-support-the-equal-justice-initiative).